# CSS: force elements besides each other without havig a parent element. Flex?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I am building a library in Ionic and one of the requirements is that I CAN NOT add classes and CAN NOT use parents elements or containers to modify or access our elements.

The search field with a button should looks ike in the image:

[image]

I have just two siblings elements:

```
<ion-button fill="clear">Button</ion-button>
<ion-searchbar clear-icon="close-circle"></ion-searchbar>
```

How could I force the search field to reduce its width and make room for the sibling button element and the button to be positioned at the right?

If I could use the container element I could easily do it with Flexbox, justify and align contents. But since this is a library we do not know what the parent element will look like and we do not want to add new elements or force developers to rely in an unwanted element.

Any help would be welcomed!

Comment: make both element `float:left` and the first one `calc(100% - W)` where W is the width of the buitton

Comment: @TemaniAfif I was thinking the same but to which element would you apply a float clearing? maybe with `display: inline-block`?

Comment: @TemaniAfif the width (W), is unkown. It depends of the word in the button. It could as short as GO, or SUBMIT.

Comment: @fcalderan to the next element using `+` or inline-block like you said but more trick to deal with white space

Comment: it has to be responsive? the width of the input + the width of the button should span the entire parent width? can you at least fix the width of the button? Can you switch the order of the elements?

Comment: @fcalderan, yes I can switch the order of the elements and it has to be responsive  but I can not fix the width of any element. I also does not know about the parent element. It could be a div, a section, a row. It should span the whole available width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use css:

```
ion-button {
  float: right;
}

ion-searchbar {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
}
```

For this to work, your ion-button should be the first element. If your searchbar is the first element instead just switch the styles.

As both of them are of same height, you don't need to clear float

**EXAMPLE:**

```css
A {
  float: right;

  /* ignore this */
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}

B {
  display: block;
  
  /* ignore this */
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<A> Some Text </A>
<B></B>
```

Comment: It does not work, it position the button at the right, but under the searchbar. The searchbar ocupies the whole width still

Comment: Updated the answer, floated element should be the first element followed by block element, then block element will occupy the remaining width

Comment: There is not a "desired fixed width". it is unknown

Comment: Sorry the fixed width is not needed, it works as expected without fixing width

Comment: No, it does not work. Elements are still in two lines. The button at the top right and the search field span the whole width. Perhaps the ionic elements work differently

Comment: did you try `width: auto` on the searchbar? It worked for me in the demo page of ionic searchbar https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar

Comment: That makes the trick! the width:auto to the searchbar. Thanks!